# What Serverless v2 scaling configuration is needed when trying to restore RDS Aurora back to point in time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I am using RDS Aurora Postgres Cluster with only one writer instance of type Serverless v2 and the capacity is set to 1 -16 ACUs. I tried to perform "restore point in time" on this cluster, however I get this error:

`Set the Serverless v2 scaling configuration on the parent DB cluster before creating a Serverless v2 DB instance.`

[image]

what does this mean?

The point is, that I have already set the Aurora Serverless v2 capacity range to 1 - 16 ACUs. What does it want?

Here, the xxx-demo-serverless-cluster is the cluster I am trying with:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

in case someone else have this same issue, you should configure the Main DB cluster itself (the one that ends with

> emo-serverless-cluster

and not the instance. The main DB cluster should have a ACU range defined previously to DB modification.

Answer (score 2):

I got this exact error in AWS console when I tried to migrate my regular RDS postgre instance snapshot to aurora serverless V2.
It would not let me continue. I noticed an aurora cluster still got created despite the error, but it disappeared like 30 seconds.
I went back to try again and second time it worked ok. Just a typical AWS console user experience.

Comment: Same, minus the working on second time... Any chance you configured it slightly differently?